# how to calculate next 5th working date form the current date in ios programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

hi i have used NSDateComponents but could not calculate the 5th date

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents weekday];
NSLog(@"Week %ld",(long)weekday);
```

Comment: Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871435/how-would-i-add-only-business-days-to-an-nsdate

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSDateComponent like this to get next date after some interval

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
dateComponents.minute = 15; //to get time after 15 minutes
dateComponents.day = 5; //to get date after 5 days
//and similarly you can calculate date or time after hour, minute, seconds day, week, etc
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[formatterWithAM dateFromString:startTime.text] options:0]
```